# Is it recommendable to deepen the understanding of a subject just by doing lot of proofs?

Tags: learning

In approx. 3 months I have an oral exam in complex analysis. I really have to do this exam well. By now I have a basic understanding of all topics which are relevant and now I am at the point to consider what the best method is to deepen my understanding. I have a good textbook which covers exactly the topics which we have discussed in our course and I thought to just start doing the excercises in this textbook (most of them are proofs but there are also the typical calculation tasks like the calculation of an integral by the different theorems)

For me this makes more sense than to just open the course script and looking at the theorems. I think that it is important to get comfortable with the theorems and I think that you can only achieve that with practicing. This is my personal experience I don't know if this is actually a good habit.

Would you recommend such an approach for deepening the understanding?

Comment: Your approach sounds  right to me - do the several kinds of exercises. If you can talk to a professor or a former student about what the exam is like that might help. Will you be asked for proofs or just statements? Calculations? Examples?

Comment: I had a couple of oral math exams and you can't really tell what the professor will ask and what not. It can be statements, calculations or examples. Maybe he wants to know the rough proof of some of the statements. Every professor is different in that regard. Normally I just prepare myself so that I know what the course is all about and I have always passed the exam but now I need to prepare very very well because the grade is very important...